# How to use twitter bootstrap modal as login form in asp .net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have started developing a site. Usually I use asp .net mvc 4  internet template because it has some per-built features, specially the Account Controller with simple membership. But I want to do more with the look of the login control. I want to use something like 
http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/loginregister-in-tabbed-interface

But with current existing account controller and account Model how am I going to achieve these? I did some Google, but I could not find any concrete example or guideline to build the login form like that with the Account Controller and Model.

So here I am posting this problem, in the The Stack overflow, where the dedicated developers always provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the StackOverflow developers first ask "What have you tried?" and then maybe point you to potential problems

Comment: Just move the account login form to the bootstrap modal.

Comment: What exactly have you tried already?